# In QML, when selecting text in textinput, the cursors go beyond the boundaries of the object

Tags: qt, qml

There is the following code in QML

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
 width: 400
 height: 300
 visible: true

     Rectangle {
         anchors.centerIn: parent
         border.color: "black"
         width: 200
         height: 40
        
         TextInput {
             anchors.fill: parent
             clip: true
             cursorVisible: true
         }
    }
}
```

If you run it on Android, enter text in the field that will not fit into TextInput and select all the text, then the cursors will be visible outside the TextInput border

Is there any way to fix this?

[Demonstration of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdm9r.jpg)

I didn't see in the documentation how to prevent the cursor from appearing if it is out of the field

Used by:
Qt 5.15.2;

Android version - the behavior is similar on 11 and 13 (most likely on other versions the same);

jdk-11.0.20.101;

ndk - 21.4.7075529

Comment: There are not enough details in your question. Qt version, OS, etc.

Comment: @folibis
Used by: Qt 5.15.2; Android version - the behavior is similar on 11 and 13 (most likely on other versions the same);  jdk-11.0.20.101; ndk - 21.4.7075529